# Feeding images to a neural network

Tags: image-processing, conv-neural-network

I have a very basic question,So kindly bear with me

The task im trying to do is classify 12 labels,There are 12 folders which each which have about 300-400 images which i plan to feed to a network,I am Not exactly sure how do i go about reading these images in the 12 folders,i know i have to convert them into arrays,What i currently have in mind is ill create 12 assignment variables(one for each label) and read each image as an array,Does this make sense or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read all the images for each folder and label the class for each image (same label) , do the same process for each folder and add the images to global list. At the end you get big collection with each item having image data(array) and corresponding label , this way you get 3600 (12*300) items. You can use this for training. Sample item [image array,class label].